# Solve the following congruence: $x(x+1)(x+2) \equiv 0 \pmod{221}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, congruences

> Find the first five solutions for,
>   $$x(x+1)(x+2) \equiv 0 \pmod{221}$$

I am very confused. By CRT,

$x(x+1)(x+2) \equiv 0 \pmod{13}$ and $x(x+1)(x+2) \equiv 0 \pmod{17}$

But these two congruences are also reckless.

Comment: When you are asked to find the *first* five solutions, where do you start? Do you want $x\ge 1$ or $x\ge 0$?

Comment: The first three solutions which come to my mind are $x=0$, $x=-1$ and $x=-2$. But perhaps it is about positive solutions ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Indeed, that's when we order solutions by "come to mind" instead of "by size" or whatever the OP may possibly intend ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x(x+1)(x+2)\equiv 0\pmod{221}\iff \begin{cases}x(x+1)(x+2)\equiv 0\pmod{13}\\x(x+1)(x+2)\equiv 0\pmod{17}\end{cases}$$

By [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma):

$$\iff \begin{cases}x\equiv \{0,-1,-2\}\pmod{13}\\x\equiv \{0,-1,-2\}\pmod{17}\end{cases}$$

By the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) (CRT) there are $9$ solutions mod $221$.

E.g., if $x\equiv 0\pmod{13}$ and $x\equiv -1\pmod{17}$, then $x\equiv 169 \pmod{221}$.

You should already know how to use CRT. You'll get:

$$x\equiv \{-2,-1,0,50,51,102,117,168,169\}\pmod{221}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $13$ ans $17$ are primes, we can infer that one of the factors $x,x+1,x+2$ is a multiple of $13$ and one (possibly the same or not) is a multiple of $17$. All in all, you end up with nine cases ...